# Why Composer install .git or .hg directories with package files?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to publish composer package. I saved `composer.json` in my package directory:

```json
{
    "name": "vendor_name/my_bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "VendorName\\MyBundle": ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir": "VendorName/MyBundle"
}
```

But when I install it (composer update), with package files will added .hg directory.

Similar behaviour can be seen in this package: https://packagist.org/packages/tom32i/file-bundle (with package files will added .git directory: http://joxi.ru/uploads/prod/20130201/560/53a/136c5290b3c0f4c6f6318445f358d1d8cf30fe13.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Quote from the documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install):

> There are two ways of downloading a package: source and dist. For stable versions composer will use the dist by default. The source is a version control repository.

The package you mentioned has no stable version, so composer downloads the source from git. Use `--prefer-dist` if you'd like composer to download package files (only happens if possible).

Answer (score 10):

[Jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648973/3467557) is great, and totally nails the solution...

In order to **more permanently** specify the `dist` version, simply add a `preferred-install` to your composer.json file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```